# Prove using Limit Theorems

Tags: limits

using limit to show that the sequence $$\left\{\frac{(-1)^n\cdot n}{2n-1}\right\}$$ is diverges.

pf:$$\frac{(-1) n^{\frac1n}}{(2n-1)^{\frac1n}}$$ with $\lim$ from $n \to\infty$, I have $-1$.

I don't think that is diverges...help plz.

Comment: The terms do not approach $0$, automatic divergence.

Comment: More precisely, the non-alternating part of the terms does not approach $0$, so the alternating sequence cannot converge.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the following claim, then this will be helpful for you.

> $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=A \iff \lim_{n\to \infty}a_{2n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{2n+1}=A.$

Clearly, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{2n}=\frac12\not=-\frac12=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{2n+1}$$

Therefore  $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the given term in the form
$(-1)^n\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{n}}$ thus the sequence diverges